# Polyurethane on damaged floor isn't creating smooth surface

Tags: wood, flooring, hardwood-floor, polyurethane, damage

I had the wood floor chipped from heavy object played on it, removing the varnish that covered that small area. I tried to fix it by first sanding, then polyurethane on a cotton swab as the affected area was fingernail size.

Here's what it was initially:

[image]

Here's the result:

[image]

Sanded with 120 grit. Did 4 coats of polyurethane with q-tip. And the polyurethane browned it a bit. But it's rough texture and not smooth, and feels unfinished.

Comment: Did you sand or steel wool between coats? The first coat tends to raise the grain. You need to resolve that before continuing. Otherwise foot traffic will buff it up anyway.

Comment: No I did not sand between coats, the minwax product I used didn't instruct me to do this. So i should sand now and do it all over again, and sand between every coat? Couldn't the issue be the q-tip, since it absorbs the liquid? Buff it up? Is that a good thing? It's in a spot with no foot traffic.

Comment: Just sand lightly (steel wool is less destructive) and apply a final coat or two. Urethane self-levels nicely, so the swab isn't likely an issue unless it's leaving fibers behind.

Comment: It's not leaving fibers, I worry because I'm using a minwax spray can, meant for direct spray on floor, but spraying on qtip instead.

Comment: I've done that. It's probably thinner than product from a can, but should still work.